# Cannot link with lrettig's react-native-stripe module

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, applepay

I followed all the steps at https://github.com/lrettig/react-native-stripe and got the error "undefined is not an object (evaluating ‘StripeNativeManager.openPaymentSetup’)." Has anyone else gotten this problem or know what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  I have resolved this by linking the React-Native_Stripe Library to my Xcode workspace.  I installed the library manually via (local) Cocoapods because the npm install was failing [Screen Shot of Linking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VUFt.png)

Comment: This is handy. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html I linked the library but I still get the same error.